# How to deal with $ in the path for xml configuration for splunk for getting logs

Tags: xml, logging, splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have this xml configuration for splunk to get logs and I used it to register the splunk agent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE logging SYSTEM "loggingdg">
<logging id="xyx" version="3">
    <file>
        <pattern>\\xyz\abc$\sample\*txt</pattern>
    </file>
</logging>
```

but I am not able to see the logs in splunk dashboard, and I have come to know the issue is that the path (pattern) should not contain $ and the legal set of characters are a-zA-Z0-9._-*/:\ , so what I can do in these case?

I register the above xml file for splunk but I am not able to see the logs.

Comment: You are getting a file from the server "xyz" in the root folder "abc".  The dollar sign indicates you are an ADMIN for both the local and remote machines.  You use a dollar sign instead of a colon when you are an admin in windows.

Comment: are events showing up in Splunk at all? If they are (but are garbled/broken), it might be fixable with props.conf